# How to define state in react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am quite new to React and wonder how this should work:

```
class App extends Component {
> 4 |   state = {
    |         ^
  5 |     bands: [],
  6 |     concerts: []
  7 |   }
```

here the error message:

```
ERROR in ./src/App.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (4:8)
```

Edit (the whole component):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    bands: [],
    concerts: []
  }
  render() {
    return <div>hei</div>
  }
}

export default App
```

Some solution to this?

Comment: Provide whole component.

Comment: It looks like you are using a non-standard (correct me if I'm wrong and this turned into a standard recently) language feature, so you will need an extra babel-transform to support this notation of class properties: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/

Comment: If the code is really as shown, you're trying to use a language feature that isn't in the language yet, it's still a [stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). Mind you, most React transpilation setups handling JSX also include that in their transpilation...

Comment: I have found this: https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx/issues/25 , it's about vue, but I think it could be the solution ?!??!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code is really as shown, you're trying to use a language feature ("class fields") that isn't in the language yet, it's still a [stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). You need to ensure whatever transpiler you're using handles transpiling that.

If you don't want to use class fields, define your `state` property in a constructor:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      bands: [],
      concerts: []
    };
  }
  render() {
    return <div>hei</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: @Kinduser The snippet is almost identical, but T.J. provided additional information about the state of the syntax proposal.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to put the state inside your constructor:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      bands: [],
      concerts: []
    };
  }
  render() {
    // Here you can access to this.state
    return <div>hei</div>
  }
}
```